# Wrong encoding at converting a .csv file into a XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I need your help again please. I convert a .csv file into a XDocument with the following method:

```
    public static XDocument ConvertCsvToXml(string sourcePath)
    {
        string[] lines;

        try
        {
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }

        var headers = lines[0].Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray();

        var xml = new XElement("FullInvoice", lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0)
           .Select(line => new XElement("Line", line.Split(';')
           .Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))));

        return new XDocument(xml);
    }
```

This works well for me, but I have some troubles with the encoding, because some characters (e.g. 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß') and their upper variants are not correctly in the XDocument..

Could you kindly advise me, where I have to set the encoding here to get this characters correct into my XDocument?

Thank you in advance and best regards from austria!

Answer (score 0):

This change did it for me.

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath, Encoding.Default);
```

If anyone faces the same troubles!